# pipe dockerfile through stdin in powershell

Tags: docker, powershell, dockerfile

According to this site: [Best practices for writing Dockerfiles](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/)
In linux it is possible to build dockerfiles by piping dockerfile in this way:

```
docker build -<<EOF
FROM busybox
RUN echo "hello world"
EOF
```

How to do it in Powershell ? Is it possible to do this in that way ?

Comment: The common name for that syntax is "here document" or "heredoc"; searching for that might help you find the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
@"
FROM busybox
RUN echo "hello world"
"@ | docker build -
```